# Ubuntu 20.04 - After suspense problem in chrome browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 - After suspense problem in chrome browser tabs, The tabs displayed with strange dots(like sand).It happens as well in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Chrome main menu (3 dots on the top right corner) → More Tools → Task Manager.
Sort by process Task name.

Find the process called GPU Process.

Click on End process.